# How to iterate over array interpreting its element as different type?

Tags: c, memory-address

There is an `arr` array with allocated memory for two `short`s (4 bytes in total). Then I fill these two elements with `ffff` and `eeee` accordingly. After I'm trying to iterate over the same allocated memory as it was allocated for 4 `char`s (also 4 bytes in total, but now I suppose be able to look up elements by 1 byte). As you can see from the output it doesn't show what I expect (get the same `0xeeeeffff` splitted to 4 separate elements). What's wrong with the code?

```
  short *arr = malloc(sizeof(short) * 2);
  *arr = 0xeeee;
  *(arr + 1) = 0xffff;
  printf("%p\n", &arr[0]);
  printf("%p\n", &arr[1]);
  // convert
  char * cnv = (char *)arr;
  printf("=======\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", cnv);
    printf("%x\n", *cnv);
    cnv++;
  }
```

The output:

```
0x759010
0x759012
=======
0x759010
ffffffee # expect 'ee'
0x759011
ffffffee # expect 'ee'
0x759012
ffffffff # expect 'ff'
0x759013
ffffffff # expect 'ff'
```

Comment: `short` and `char` passed to printf via `...` are passed as `int`s. That's how `...` works. You need to use `"%hhx"` to interpret that `int` as a char (in gcc anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%x` expects an `unsigned int`, not a `char`, and thus your program has undefined behaviour. You need `%hhx`.

Comment: why did you cast the (unsigned short *) pointer to (void *) here `printf("%p\n", (void*)&arr[0]);`?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: Because that's how `printf` works. Your original code has undefined behaviour. See the manual.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `char` is signed type on your platform. The hex `0xee` is treated as a negative number (-18). When that number is promoted to an integer, it's binary representation is such that it is `0xffffffee` in hex.

The same thing happens with `0xff`.

If you print it using `%d`, you can see the negative value in the output.

```
printf("%x %d\n", *cnv, *cnv);
```